# How to send one program to sleep mode (but keep the rest of OS alive)

Tags: linux, sleep, mathematica

Is there a way to send only one program to sleep mode (in this case mathematica on linux) and keep the rest of the operating system alive?

Comment: was answered here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135876/how-to-pause-a-running-evaluation-and-continue-it-later

Answer (score 1):

Try suspending the program:

- `kill -TSTP $PID` suspends the process
- `kill -CONT $PID` resumes it ([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2107/how-to-suspend-and-resume-processes))

You can lookup `$PID` in `ps -Al`.